# GraphQL as aggregator service?

Tags: java, graphql

On most of the resources on google, I see one of the major advantage of graphql is said to be its ability to be as aggregator service but I did not find any concrete example how it is different from other http endpoints(or Rest endpoints) ?

My understanding is that in case of GraphQL, there will be single http endpoint for everything. Then graphql server will determine which particular 
data fetcher will be called. That is provided in very configurable way.

But in case of other MVC based architecture or rest based architecture, end points are separate for each request and then the flow start.

So in a way graphql provides the single entry point(or we can say address) for each request then graphql take care of further branching, but in other above
mentioned architecture there are separate addresses(or endpoints) for resources/request. Is it  because of this reason we say graphql can work as aggregator service or is it something else ?

Answer (score 0):

The GraphQL's main advantage is to provide to the client ability to query everything (objects) it needed and display it to user without discussing/creating specification for every request/response in the application. And in some cases clients need different responses for the same request (eg views might look differently for web and mobile clients).

I believe you can create multiple GraphQL endpoint in your application based on context of your domain, but it might be misleading in most cases.

Comment: My question is primarily from aggregation point of view i.e. How it can help as aggregator service ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your question is about advantages of aggregator design pattern then?
Because graphql on the backend side is working like aggregator and I believe there is no other option to implement it.