# Graphql only allows one root query?

Tags: graphql

As this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql) says

> The one requirement is that there must be exactly one root query, and
> ...

Consider the schema

```
type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    text: String!
    category: String
    author: Author!
}
 
type Author {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    thumbnail: String
    posts: [Post]!
}

# The Root Query for the application
type Query {
    recentPosts(count: Int, offset: Int): [Post]!
}
```

Does it mean I can not declare another root queries like below ? Is there any other query type apart from root query ?

```
# Another  query
type Query {
    getPost(id: Int): [Post]!
}

# Another  query
type Query {
    getAuthor(id: Int): [Author]!
}
```

Comment: How is it related to Java? And the link is broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GraphQL, there are three operations: `query`, `mutation` and `subscription`. Each of these operations has a single type associated with it, although you are only required to provide a type for `query` -- the other two are optional. We refer to these types as [root operation types](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Root-Operation-Types).

We specify the root operation types for a schema like this:

```
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}
```

You can name your query type anything at all (`Query`, `RootQuery`, `FooBar`, etc.). However, if you name it `Query`, the above step can be omitted (GraphQL will simply assume that the three root operation types will be named `Query`, `Mutation` and `Subscription`).

Our query type has to be an [object type](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Objects), so we use the `type` keyword to define it and provide at least one field for it:

```
type Query {
  getPost(id: Int): Post!
}

type Post {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  text: String!
}
```

With this schema, we can now write a query. We haven't specified a `Mutation` or `Subscription` type, so we can only perform one operation -- a `query`:

```
query {
  getPost(id: 5) {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

As we can see, we refer to Query as a *root* operation type because it represents the *root* or entry to the rest of our schema. Every executable document you send to your server has to start at this root, although the type will differ depending on the operation (query, mutation or subscription).

Query is an object type, which means we can add additional fields to it:

```
type Query {
  getPost(id: Int): Post
  getAuthor(id: Int): Author
}

type Post {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  text: String!
}

type Author {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

Now we can write a different query:

```
query {
  getAuthor(id: 7){
    id
    name
  }
}
```

or even request both fields:

```
query {
  getPost(id: 3) {
    id
    title
  }
  getAuthor(id: 11){
    id
    name
  }
}
```

You wouldn't define `Query` twice as shown in your question -- you would simply add additional fields like as shown above.

For additional information, please see [the spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018) and the [official tutorial](https://graphql.org/learn/).

Comment: can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58853654/graphql-as-aggregator-service/58854082?noredirect=1#comment103984865_58854082 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in GraphQL there is only a single root Query. You can however "namespace" your queries on the root Query by providing a "stub" field + resolver, like shown below.

```
type Booking {
    _id: ID!
    event: Event!
    user: User!
    createdAt: String!
    updatedAt: String!
}

type Event {
    _id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String!
    date: String!
}

type RootQuery {
    events: [Event!]!
    bookings: [Booking!]!
}

schema {
    query: RootQuery
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate `You can however "namespace" your queries on the root Query by providing a "stub" field + resolver, like shown below.` ? Also if i can declare only one root query say `POST`, but I want to get only `Author` how can I get it ?